# Do Object.seal and .freeze deliver different results with regard to the return type in Typescript?

Tags: typescript

I want to protect the object content of a constant from being changed at runtime. This affects both the change in the object structure and the content of the object. The method of choice here is Object.freeze.

```ts
interface iRO<T> {
    readonly [key: string]: T | null;
}

const nc: iRO<HTMLElement> = {
    main: document.querySelector("body"),
    aside: document.querySelector("body > aside"),
}

const go: iRO<HTMLElement> = Object.seal({
    main: document.querySelector("body"),
    aside: document.querySelector("body > aside"),
})

const nogo: iRO<HTMLElement> = Object.freeze({
    main: document.querySelector("body"),
    aside: document.querySelector("body > aside"),
})
```

As an example, I have given three constants with the same content. With the constants "nc" and "go" the compilation works fine. The compiler complains at "nogo":

*»Type 'Readonly<{ main: HTMLBodyElement | null; aside: Element | null; }>' is not assignable to type 'iRO'. Property 'aside' is incompatible with index signature. Type 'Element | null' is not assignable to type 'HTMLElement | null'. Type 'Element' is missing the following properties from type 'HTMLElement': accessKey, accessKeyLabel, autocapitalize, dir, and 107 more.«*

I do not understand that. Object.freeze should just as little influence the assigned type as its little brother Object.seal?

Here's a [Typescript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.0.5#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAmAJQPIB4AqA%20ZAbwCgBIKCOAEwHsQAbAT2QG0BrCRgLmQGcwooAOYBdHjmQAfZCACu9egG5iAX2LEEdfjIQ902ABI4AsgBkAovQgBbCOAIBeImWtxQPWglm3wAOgCOstCMAMoQVghgNFAAFABEAEY0VIxxAJQANGRwvMBUEB40Xj5gAUFQoeEQkdHxSSnIBDl5EOlZahpaYMhCNHqYWEZmljZ2YI7IGAkAVtWlvJT0MSSkru7Int5jZcFhEVGxicmpmdm5%20YXF24G7VTWH9cxN562nKmnqmiDaIDS9-YYTBYrCUJlNZpFfDAKBAAF4QZbEZDI5BrECXLZ%20G4VPZzWpHFJtM4tDElHY4u4HOrHRrIZr5InvYhAA)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is with how TypeScript determines the type of the object *before* being assigned to the variable on the left-hand side.

When you use:

```
const nc: iRO<HTMLElement> = {
```

This tells TypeScript that the object on the right must conform to `iRO<HTMLElement>`. That is, its values must be of type `HTMLElement | null`. This is OK for `nc` because `document.querySelector("body")` with the proper type argument can give such a type. One way of looking at the first version is:

```
const nc: iRO<HTMLElement> = {
    main: document.querySelector<HTMLElement>("body"),
    aside: document.querySelector<HTMLElement>("body > aside"),
}
```

This also works with `Object.seal` because `Object.seal` *does not do anything*, type-wise, with the argument. Its type definition is:

```
seal<T>(o: T): T;
```

But `Object.freeze` is different. Its type definition is:

```
freeze<T>(o: T): Readonly<T>;
```

Since it returns a *new type*, its `T` isn't free to change to satisfy generics. The type of the object passed in must be static. It's like:

```
const obj = {
    main: document.querySelector("body"),
    aside: document.querySelector("body > aside"),
};
const nogo: iRO<HTMLElement> = Object.freeze(obj);
```

But the parameter has a type of

```
const obj: {
    main: HTMLBodyElement | null;
    aside: Element | null;
}
```

and the resulting type returned by `Object.freeze` is

```
Readonly<{
    main: HTMLBodyElement | null;
    aside: Element | null;
}>
```

It's a *new type* - and an `Element` can't be assigned to an `HTMLElement`.

If `Object.seal` returned a *new type*, rather than the same type as the argument, you'd see the same problem with it as well. But since `Object.seal` returns the same type as its argument, it doesn't result in the same problem.

Use the generic parameter to `querySelector` to fix it:

```
const nc = Object.freeze({
    main: document.querySelector("body"),
    aside: document.querySelector<HTMLElement>("body > aside"),
})
```

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer. I got that. These are my first steps with TypeScript.

Answer (score 2):

I think that `document.querySelector("body")` returns a type `HTMLBodyElement` which extends `HTMLElement`.
But `document.querySelector("body > aside")` doesn't return `HTMLElement` but `Element` and therefore is just only the subinterface.

And so if using `iRO<HTMLElement>` you expect that all keys at least extends from `HTMLElement`.
When using a normal object or `Object.seal`, you doing a smart type cast, but using `Object.freeze` freezes your object and therefore it detects that your `aside` will only be of type `Element` but not `HTMLElement`

But you could do this:

```
const nogo: Readonly<iRO<HTMLElement>> = Object.freeze({
    main: document.querySelector("body"),
    aside: document.querySelector("body > aside") as HTMLElement | null,
})
```

---

Edit:

Seeing the answer from @CertainPerformance, s/he is right in better using `document.querySelector<HTMLElement>("body > aside")` instead of `document.querySelector("body > aside") as HTMLElement | null`